# Override some material-ui class styles but preserve the default ones

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, overriding

I'm working with [material-ui tooltip](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/) and want to change just one style (margin) for the `tooltipPlacementTop` class:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      tooltipPlacementTop: {
         margin: '4px 0' 
      },
    });
    ....
    <Tooltip classes={{ tooltipPlacementTop: classes.tooltipPlacementTop }} >
```

But this way it overrides **all** styles that this class had by default. How can I preserve the default material-ui styles and change only one i need?

---

I found the issue, in my case `Tooltip` was a custom component that uses material-ui tooltip and I actually overrided the classes property in it...

Closing the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the material ui api docs you can always check out the [implementation of the component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Tooltip/Tooltip.js#L141). If I understand you correctly you want to override the margin of `tooltipPlacementTop`, but want to keep the rest of the styles. If you add styles this way they will extend the existing styles and not overwrite them. You probably overlooked the theme.breakpoint.

Check this out

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tooltipPlacementTop: {
    margin: "4px 0",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      margin: "4px 0"
    }
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ marginTop: 100 }}>
      <Tooltip title="hi there" classes={classes} placement="top">
        <h2>Hover me!</h2>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
const { Tooltip, makeStyles } = MaterialUI;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tooltipPlacementTop: {
    margin: "4px 0",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      margin: "4px 0"
    }
  }
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
      <Tooltip title="hi there" classes={classes} placement="top">
        <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Hover me!</h2>
      </Tooltip>
      <Tooltip title="hi there (normal)" placement="top">
        <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 50 }}>Hover me (default)!</h2>
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: oh...I found the issue. in my case Tooltip was a custom component that uses materil-ui tooltip and I actually override the `classes` property in it...